# How to pass data from a child component to a parent component and then to another child component?

Tags: angular

I have three components:

```
Parent
    childOne
    childTwo
```

At my Parent component I have something like this:

```
...
<app-childOne (formReady)="addChildForm('email', $event) ></app-childOne>

<app-childTwo [form]="form" [resumo]="resumo"></app-childTwo>
...
```

At my ChildOneComponent I have this output

```
@Output() formReady = new EventEmitter<FormGroup>();

ngOnInit(){
...
this.formReady.emit(this.form);
...

}
```

So when I select a value into my form inside the childOne component, the form inside the parent component is updated.
But I need to send the value to the childtwo component every time that value from the parent component changes.

So I tried at my childTwo Component:

```
@Input() form;
brokerResumo;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.brokerResumo(this.form.sms.brokerId);
  }

  getBrokerResumo = (brokerId) =>
    (this.brokerResumo = this.brokers.find(
      (element) => element.id === brokerId
    ));
```

But It didn't work because ngOnInit work once.

Comment: You can create a service and call it from any component

Answer (score 0):

you can move that line from ngOnInit to ngOnChange:

```
  ngOnChange() {
    this.brokerResumo(this.form.sms.brokerId);
  }
```

Comment: I tried this once but It didn't work because the from group who has the change is from the other child. This approach works with the parent form.